# How to load dependencies from an s3 bucket AND a separate event JSON?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, dependencies

The dependencies for my AWS Lambda function were larger than the allowable limits, so I uploaded them to an s3 bucket. I have seen how to use an s3 bucket as an event for a Lambda function, but I need to use these packages *in conjunction* with a separate event. The s3 bucket only contains python modules (`numpy`, `nltk`, etc.) **not** the event data used in the Lambda function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event data will come in from whatever event source that you configure. Refer the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) for the S3 event source.

As for the dependencies themself, you will have to zip the whole codebase (code + dependencies) and use that as a deployment package. You can find detailed intructions on that on the docs. For reference, here the one for [NodeJS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html) and [Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html).

Protip: A better way to manage dependencies is to use Lambda Layer. You can create a layer will all your dependencies and then add it to the function that make use of these. Read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

If your dependencies are still above the 512MB hard limit of AWS Lambda, you may consider using AWS Elastic File System with Lambda.

With this now you can essentially attach a network storage to your lambda function. I have personally used it to load huge reference files which are over the limit of Lambda's file storage. For a walkthrough you can refer to this article by AWS. To pick the conclusion from the article:

EFS for Lambda allows you to share data across function invocations, read large reference data files, and write function output to a persistent and shared store. After configuring EFS, you provide the Lambda function with an access point ARN, allowing you to read and write to this file system. Lambda securely connects the function instances to the EFS mount targets in the same Availability Zone and subnet.

You can read the Read the announcement [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-a-shared-file-system-for-your-lambda-functions/)

Edit 1: Added EFS for lambda info.

Comment: The reason I dumped them in s3 is because my dependencies zip file was way too big. In s3 I have a larger storage limit. Can I access dependencies here instead is my question. I tried using Lambda Layers but my files are still too large.

Comment: @DesiPilla, you cannot "use" dependencies if they are on S3. You still have to pass them on tot he python interpretor while using them. I've updated the answer with a possible solution to get aroudn the 512MB AWS lambda storage limit.

Comment: @DesiPilla, if the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, it has taken me until today to implement EFS in my project. And it HAS solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: A Useful answer, Saved my day.